# What stats does the simulacrum of an golden great wyrm have?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, simulacrum

With the spell [simulacrum](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/simulacrum.html#simulacrum) you can create a half-real illusion of a creature with HD no greater than 2xCL and it has half the original's HD and abilities according to that.

Now dragons have age categories. Would a simulacrum of a [gold](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/dragon.html#metallic-dragon-gold) great wyrm (30HD) have the abilities of a great wyrm at half strength so to say or would it have the abilities of a golden dragon with half the HD, in this case somewhat between juvenile (14HD) and young adult (16HD)?

The size should be that of a great wyrm, as you have a disguise check so observers think it is the real thing unless they beat your disguise result. But what about abilities that only the older dragons get? Like Divine Aid, Fire Aura, Luck,

Answer (score 6):

It would be as a Juvenile dragon according to RAW.

> It appears to be the same as the original, but it has only half of the
>   real creature's levels or HD (**and the appropriate hit points, feats,
>   skill ranks, and special abilities for a creature of that level or
>   HD**).

(emphasis mine)
The illusion makes it look like a 30HD great wyrm, but in reality it's only a 15HD Juvenile. True Dragons' power is derived from their HD and level in True Dragon, which determines which age category they belong in.

Comment: While I think this is a good way to handle the situation, it requires reading a _ton_ into that text that it does not explicitly say. Calling this “RAW” is therefore... questionable, at the very least. An honest RAW analysis might consider this a possibility, but only one among many, and perhaps not the most likely one. To say that this _is_ “the” singular, solitary answer “according to RAW,” is inaccurate, in my view. I think you should tone down that claim.

Comment: I genuinely can't see any other way of honestly reading the bolded text, even all these years later.

Comment: No one knows what that text means. It’s nearly worthless in its vagueness, and it’s not at all clear what we’re meant to do with it. But we can’t switch every possible creature to its “juvenile form,” because the overwhelming majority of creatures don’t have one. It’s possible we’re meant to homebrew some such thing for other creatures, or possible that *simulacrum* treats dragons differently from every other possible target in the game, but since **nothing written in the rules says any of that**, we can’t claim it’s the rules *as written*. They didn’t write that.

Comment: But we are specifically dealing with a creature which does have different abilities at lower HD, which seems to be covered under the rules as written. I agree 5e is awfully written, but in the specific instance the question was addressing, the raw seems to cover it.

Comment: The rules as written do not say that the simulacrum should have the stats of a creature of half the _age_ of the target creature, which this is also doing. It is not written that you’re supposed to do that. This is not RAW.

Comment: It says HD, dragon ages are determined by HD.